# copy file to folder have same name with different extension in parent directory

Tags: shell

my files are

```
1996-08-30T02.11.41.940_10

1997-03-04T17.24.17.650_17

1997-04-01T15.43.26.390_20
```

and folders are

```
1996-08-30T02.11.41.940_5.1

1997-03-04T17.24.17.650_5.0

1997-04-01T15.43.26.390_4.5
```

the files and folders are in same directories. I want to move file to a folder whose name is same with different extension
ex:
The file 1996-08-30T02.11.41.940_10 should be move in folder 1996-08-30T02.11.41.940_5.1

I Have tried this, but no use

```
for file in ./*T* ; do mv -v $file ${file%_*}; done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close:

```
$ for file in ./* ; do [ -f "$file" ] && mv -v "$file" "${file%_*}"*/; done
'./1996-08-30T02.11.41.940_10' -> './1996-08-30T02.11.41.940_5.1/1996-08-30T02.11.41.940_10'
'./1997-03-04T17.24.17.650_17' -> './1997-03-04T17.24.17.650_5.0/1997-03-04T17.24.17.650_17'
'./1997-04-01T15.43.26.390_20' -> './1997-04-01T15.43.26.390_4.5/1997-04-01T15.43.26.390_20'
```

Notes:

1. Unless you specifically want the shell to mangle things, always put shell variables in double quotes.
2. We added test `[ -f "$file" ]` so that we only try to move regular files, not directories.
3. The directory will match `${file%_*}"*/`.  We are assuming, as per the question discription, that there is only one such directory.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a similar approach to @John1024, but relies on bash features.

First, create an associative array, mapping the "common root" to the directory name:

```
declare -A dirs
for d in */; do dirs["${d%_*}"]=$d; done
```

Then, iterate over the files, and move into the directory with the common root

```
for f in *; do 
    [[ -f $f ]] || continue
    root=${f%_*}
    if [[ ${dirs[$root]} ]]; then
        mv -v "$f" "${dirs[$root]}"
    else
        echo "error: no directory for '$f'"
    fi
done
```

```
'1996-08-30T02.11.41.940_10' -> '1996-08-30T02.11.41.940_5.1/1996-08-30T02.11.41.940_10'
'1997-03-04T17.24.17.650_17' -> '1997-03-04T17.24.17.650_5.0/1997-03-04T17.24.17.650_17'
'1997-04-01T15.43.26.390_20' -> '1997-04-01T15.43.26.390_4.5/1997-04-01T15.43.26.390_20'
```

This addresses the assumption that there is only one directory with the common root: the files will be moved into the *last* such dir (alphabetically)